# Theoretical signature of document between two parties

Tags: cryptography, private, theory, public

The problem is as follows:
Write down the deposit of a document by A to C (so A sends document to C) after A and B signed this document.

Use only the following notations:

- H(.) : hash function
- (KX+, KX-) pair of keys for entity X
- (KsA,B) symmetrical key used by A and B

So I thought this at first:

A and B must sign (symmetrically I assume) the document: KsA,B(H(m))

Then, A must sign with public key the document before sending to C: KA+(KsA,B(H(m))

But I am not very sure of my answer. Perhaps you could explain if this is correct or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this question is off-topic here, and probably belongs on [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).